# Unexplained Characters Within Output of C Program

Tags: c, arrays

I made a simple c program for testing out inputting experience points in a simple text based rpg. It's by no means final in any way, just for testing. It uses an integer array with 6 indices (0 to 5) to store 6 different "Levels". These "Levels" increment by 1 depending on a number entered by the user.

All it does now is prompts for an integer input, then passes that input and the array into another function. This function uses an if/else if structure to determine if the entered number is between a certain range, and depending on that range will increment the integer value of a specific array index by 1. The array is then passed back to "main". This is within a while loop, so while I do not input -1, the loop will run, passing the entered integer value and array each time.

After entering -1 the program will call another function that passes the array into it. This last function uses a for loop to output the values of each index position in the array. Then the program ends.

For example, if I enter the number 5 six times, the number 15 ten times, and the number 35 once, the output should be this:

```
T O T A L S

Level 1    6
Level 2    10
Level 3    0
Level 4    1
Level 5    0
Level 6    0
```

What I am instead getting is the inclusion of decimal points in the output like this:

```
T O T A L S

Level 1    .6
Level 2    .10
Level 3    .0
Level 4    .1
Level 5    .0
Level 6    .0
```

Why would this be happening and what should I do to get rid of them?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int update_level(int points, int arr[]);
void display_levels(int arr[]);


int main(void)
{
    int pointVal = 0;
    int *proxy;
    int pointArr[6] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    while (pointVal != -1)
    {
        printf("Player points (-1 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &pointVal);

        proxy = update_level(pointVal, pointArr);
    }

    display_levels(proxy);
    return 0;
}

int update_level(int points, int arr[])
{
    if (points >= 0 && points < 15)
    {
        arr[0]++;
    }
    else if (points >= 15 && points < 25)
    {
        arr[1]++;
    }
    else if (points >= 25 && points < 35)
    {
        arr[2]++;
    }
    else if (points >= 35 && points < 45)
    {
        arr[3]++;
    }
    else if (points >= 45 && points < 55)
    {
        arr[4]++;
    }
    else if (points >= 55)
    {
        arr[5]++;
    }

    return arr;
}

void display_levels(int arr[])
{
    int level;

    puts("\nT O T A L S\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        level = i + 1;
        printf("Level %d%5c%d\n", level, "", arr[i]);   
    }
}
```

Comment: I should also add that if I remove the puts("\nT O T A L S\n"); line of code, the decimals disappear. Again, no idea why.

Comment: Aren't you getting a warning from your compiler for the last printf? If not, try turning the warning levels and look at them in detail.

Comment: Did you try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`? The warnings should help you fix the problem

Comment: One second, I'll look

Comment: Yeah. I am using Dev C++ and I get the following warnings: [Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
and: [Warning] return makes integer from pointer without a cast

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function `display_levels`, you are attempting to print a character with `"%5c"` but giving a string literal `""` as argument which leads to UB (undefined behaviour) which is a pandora box of surprises.
You should replace argument with `' '` for the intended result.

```
printf("Level %d%5c%d\n", level, ' ', arr[i]);
/*                               ^^^            */
```

Alternatively you can replace `"%5c"` with `"%5s"`.